# Varnish configuration with phpMyAdmin and VirtulHosts

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm having problem configuring **default.vcl**: *varnish* is blocking the Login into phpMyAdmin and always show me the Login page after authentication.

The web server must only host WordPress sites and the phpMyAdmin where each user can administer his database.

```
http://phpMyAdmin.domain.com //for phpMyAdmin where users access their database
http://www.site1.com  
http://www.site2.com  
http://www.site3.com //and so on
```

Where I'm in error or missing something?

This is my actual default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}

acl purge {
    # Web server with plugin which will issue PURGE requests
    "127.0.0.1";
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        ban("req.url ~ ^" + req.url + "$ && req.http.host == " + req.http.host);
    }

    # Normalize content-encoding
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|lzma|tbz)(\?.*|)$") {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove cookies and query string for real static files
    if (req.url ~ "^/[^?]+\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|txt|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png|gz|zip|lzma|bz2|tgz|tbz)(\?.*|)$") {
       unset req.http.cookie;
       set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
    }

    # Don't cache backend
    if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "pmacloud") {
        return(pass);
    }

    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
  # Don't store backend
  if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)" || req.url ~ "preview=true" || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php") {
    return (hit_for_pass);
  }
  if ( (!(req.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)|login)")) || (req.request == "GET") ) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 4h;
  }
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|txt|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
     set beresp.ttl = 30d;
  } #else {
  # set beresp.do_esi = true;
  #}
}
sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}

sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to enable access to phpMyAdmin is to add in

**sub vcl_recv**

```
if (req.http.Host == "phpMyAdmin.domain.com") {
   return (pass);
}
```

**sub vcl_fetch**

```
if (req.http.Host == "phpMyAdmin.domain.com") {
    return (hit_for_pass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your vcl_fetch you are dropping `set-cookie` header for everything else but WordPress specific URLs.

Speficically:

```
# Don't store backend
if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)" || req.url ~ "preview=true" || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php") {
  return (hit_for_pass);
}
if ( (!(req.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)|login)")) || (req.request == "GET") ) {
  unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  set beresp.ttl = 4h;
}
```

You need to adjust both these lines to look for phpMyAdmin specific URLs or domains.

For example if phpMyAdmin is always hosted on `phpmyadmin.domain.com` you could do the following:

```
# Don't store backend
if ( 
  req.http.host ~ "phpmyadmin"
  || req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)"
  || req.url ~ "preview=true"
  || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php"
) {
  return (hit_for_pass);
}
if (
  req.http.host ~ "phpmyadmin"
  || (!(req.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin|comments-post.php|cron.php)|login)"))
  || (req.request == "GET")
) {
  unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  set beresp.ttl = 4h;
}
```